# Как правильно выбрать primary key для oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Подскажите, как правильно определить primary key, для случая, когда необходима максимально быстрая вставка.
Уникальный идентификатор строки представляется в следующем виде: 'ID:domain.local-46424-1507204866234-1:1:187331:1:1'.
Сам алгоритм вставки представлен в следующем виде:
1. поиск, существует ли уже строка с указанным идентификатором базе (оператор select по данной строке)
2. если строки не существует, происходит вставка

Подскажите наиболее оптимальный вариант организации таблицы:

1. Строку вида 'ID:domain.local-46424-1507204866234-1:1:187331:1:1' делать как primary key. Полагаю это не самый быстрый вариант
2. Делать primary key как числовой автоинкремент. Добавить числовой столбец как hashCode от строки, сделать на него индекс и искать по нему. Логику проверки строкового идентификатора реализовать на уровне приложения для случая коллизии hashCode
3. Сделать композитный primary key из столбцов hashCode(str_id) и str_id. В этом случае проверка на коллизии будет на уровне бд. Вопрос в том, насколько это будет затратно, имея ввиду создания индекса на эти два столбца первичного ключа.
4. Может быть есть более простой способ?

Comment: Какие предполагаются запросы к базе?

Comment: Зачем нужен композитный ключ из хеш-кода и строки, если строка и так заведомо уникальна и поиск по ней по индексу будет ни как не медленнее чем по ней же с хеш-кодом. Тут вопрос в том, будут ли ссылаться на эту таблицу из других (foreign key). Ссылаться по такой длинной строке мягко говоря не удобно, потому что ее придется хранить и в других таблицах. Тогда числовой id. Если же на таблицу ссылок не будет, то можно попробовать и саму строку сделать primary, конечно объем индекса будет больше, на сколько это скажется на скорости, сказать сложно

Comment: По 2 варианту - очень даже рабочий, только логику в приложении реализовывать ни к чему, если вы укажете `where hashCode=XX and Code=YY` при наличии индекса по hashCode он сам отлично по нему найдет те несколько строк коллизий и среди них выберет нужную по самой ключевой строке

Comment: A K Запросы - только INSERT и SELECT

Comment: Mike, foreign ключей не будет

Comment: Кстати, посмотрите `MERGE`, если у вас большой объем вставок и перед каждой вы отдельным запросом проверяете существование (рискуя пропустить существующую строку, если несколько потоков одновременно вставляют), то выполнение проверки и вставки одним запросом будет скорее всего быстрее. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606 (в части using пишется select новых данных from DUAL)

Comment: Спасибо, Mike, думаю это поможет!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решили последовать совету Mike.

Обобщая, в качестве решения решено использовать следующий вариант:
Делать primary key как числовой автоинкремент. Добавить числовой столбец как hashCode от строки, сделать на него индекс и искать по нему. Логику проверки строкового идентификатора добавить в условие WHERE для случая коллизии hashCode:

`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE hashCode=XX and Code=YY`

Спасибо всем участникам за помощь, и MaxU за полезную информацию! :)

Answer (score 1):

[Здесь интересные тесты проводили - прочтите](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/is-oracles-sysguid-a-good-choice-for-a-primary-key.html)

`SEQUENCE` - пожалуй самый быстрый вариант, но генерит больше REDO, по сравнению с `SYS_GUID()`

В общем в любом случае я бы выбирал из этих двух вариантов, если у вас нет естественного кандидата - т.е. заведомо уникальный столбец, который содержит данные (не искусственный как `SEQUENCE` или `SYS_GUID()`)

Comment: Интересный тест, взял на заметку.

Comment: @0xdb, да, мне тоже понравилось